# How to define a connection string from a Library

Tags: dbconnection

I have three projects :
1)NorthwindContextLib that holds my Northwind Context and my App.config file to connect to the sqlServer database
2)NorthwindEntitiesLib that holds the Northwind entities
3)NorthwindWeb being the user interface

In the Startup.cs file in NorthwindWeb , I wish to access the database connection held in the NorthwindContextLib config file. Is there a way of using an ExeConfigurationFileMap object that references the configuration file to use instead of the default application configuration file ?
Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: Please provide more details about your projects: what language do you use? what database?

Comment: c# ,  Northwind database.